# How to write a branch function correctly

Tags: math-mode

I tried to write a branch function as follows:

```
 $Pr{NC|\alpha}=$ \[ \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+p(\alpha + \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 0\leq x \leq \beta \\
      (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+4p\alpha\beta)^{n-1} & \beta\leq x\leq \beta-1\\
      (1-p)^{n-1} (1-p(\alpha - \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 1-\beta\leq x\leq 1 \\

\end{array} 
\right. \]
```

but the `Pr{NC|\alpha}=` appears a lone while the function on the second line, How I can put them on the same line?

Comment: You might want to start consulting an introductory LaTeX manual. Put all the math inside `\[...\]` and also load the `amsmath` package and use the `cases` env, then the `{` and the array is build in, less to type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The version of parentheses for probability is not obvious.  A suggestion (one displaymath in `\[`...`\]`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 

\[ 
\Pr\{\mathrm{NC}|\alpha\}= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+p(\alpha + \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 0\leq x \leq \beta \\
      (1-p)^{n-1}(1-p+4p\alpha\beta)^{n-1} & \beta\leq x\leq \beta-1\\
      (1-p)^{n-1} (1-p(\alpha - \beta)^{2})^{n-1} & 1-\beta\leq x\leq 1 \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to fit size? because it exceeded  the line width ?

Comment: How to print the number of equation for example : (1)

Comment: Personal taste (apart from using `amsmath`'s `cases` environment): I would use `\mid` instead of a simple `|`. Spacing is better.

Comment: @campa Yes. And probably `Pr( )`,  better spacing after `\left\{`, additional commas, vertical spacing etc. But OP is a beginner, so adding upright `Pr(NC` with no information about `amsmath` seems to be enough.

Comment: @Hamm `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` in the place of `\[ ...\]`.  And without MWE you cannot expect a correction of  horizontal positioning.